# Need code for differential equation analysis $\dot{x} = rx \ln \frac{K}{x}$

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I'm analyzing the Gompertz population model: ${\dot{x} = rx \ln \frac{K}{x}}$.

Can anyone kindly write the mathematica code for this equation so I can vary the parameters so I can intepret what's going on with the parameters $r$ and $K$?

Initial code was

```
 Manipulate[ (sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == r*x[t]*log[K/x[t]], x[0] == 0.001}, x[t], {t, 0, 1000}]; Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]), {{r, 0.01}, 0, 0.05}, {{K, 5}, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no well-focused question in this post; the OP is simply asking for somebody to act as a free coding service.

Comment: What do you mean there is no well focused question?  I am trying to analyze the dynamical system, I know that I need to use the Manipulate plot in mathematica, but since I'm relative new to mathematica I don't know all the functions.  I am simply asking someone to provide me the code so I can visualize what's going on.

Comment: What have you tried? The first place to start with any new language is the docs, e.g. [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html). You might try something like `DSolve[x'[t] == x[t]*Log[1/x[t]], ...]` then (with minor adaptions necessary).

Comment: You are making no effort on your own. You don't even bother to give necessary information such as the initial condition on `x[t]` or the range of the parameters `k` and `r`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I tried this code Manipulate[ (sol = 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == rx[t]*ln (K/x[t]), x[0] == 0.001}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 1000}]; 
  Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10}]), {{r, 0.01}, 0, 0.05}, {{K, 5}, 0, 10}] but it didn't work

Comment: `ln` isn't a function in Mathematica. It's `Log`. Do you need `NDSolve`? You can solve something as simple as this analytically. And (hopefully) finally `rx[t] =!= r*x[t]`. Please. Read the docs. Oh and you're using `Manipulate` wrong here.

Comment: Manipulate[ (sol = 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == r*x[t]*log (K/x[t]), x[0] == 0.001}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 1000}]; 
  Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10}]), {{r, 0.01}, 0, 0.05}, {{K, 5}, 0, 10}]

@b3m2a1 This still wouldn't work.  Can you spot any other mistakes? Of course I can solve this analytically, but I'm in a dynamical system class therefore my professor asked me to use mathematica to visualize what's going on with the equation.

Comment: I mean you can make Mathematica solve this analytically. In any case, yes, I can see a very simple one that you should know from reading the docs. When I fix this the code works. Mathematica reads `log(a)` to be `log*a`. You want to use `Log` as a function. Past this I'm going to ask you to figure it out on your own. I think you can do it.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Manipulate[ (sol = 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == r*x[t]*log[K/x[t]], x[0] == 0.001}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 1000}]; 
  Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10}]), {{r, 0.01}, 0, 0.05}, {{K, 5}, 0, 10}]

Alright I fixed it, but it still giving me errors, perhaps it is from my range?

Comment: @b3m2a1Strange because this code works for me Manipulate[
 (x0 = 0.01;
  conSol = 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == r*x[t]*(1 - x[t]), x[0] == x0}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 100}];
  conPlot = Plot[x[t] /. conSol, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}];
  discSol = NestList[# + r*#*(1 - #) &, x0, 100];
  discPlot = ListPlot[discSol, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {0, 1}];
  Show[discPlot, conPlot]
  ), {r, 0.01, 4}]

Comment: Is `log` a function in Mathematica? Look it up. `Log` certainly is, though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 ah I see it is because of the capitalization.  Thanks!  It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
Clear[x]
x = DSolveValue[{x'[t] == r x[t] Log[k/x[t]], x[0] == .001}, x, t];
Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. {r -> rr, k -> kk}], {t, 0, 1}],
  {{rr, 1, "r"}, 1, 11, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{kk, .1, "k"}, .05, 2., .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: The OP actually did give the IC in a comment (`x[0] == .001`). For performance it might be worth tossing the standard `Evaluate` in the first argument of `Plot`. I'm imagining someone will naively come and copy this some day for something more complicated and their `Plot` will take forever.

Comment: @b3m2a1. Shouldn't have to dig such info out a comment. But you make two good points and I have modified my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is quite clear that the equation in question is easily transformed into a trivial equation

```
y'[z]==q-y[z]
```

by the replacements:  `y=Log[x]`, `z=r t` and `q=Log[k]`.

This equation can be then either solved, or its solution could be taken from the nearest textbook on differential equations.

However, I will make these transformations on the screen step-by-step just for a pleasure. There, the initial equation is:

```
eq1 = x'[t] == r*x[t]*Log[k/x[t]]
```

@Itsnhantransitive Please note that the capital K is reserved in Mma, and it is generally recommended not to use capital letters for private variables. Therefore, here stays small k.

Let us now make the following replacement: `x[t]->Exp[y[z]]`:

```
eq2 = eq1 /. x -> (Exp[y[r*#]] &) /. t ->z/r
```

[image]

Let us cancel the common factor, then represent `Log[E^-y[z] k]` as `-y[z]+Log[k]` and finally replace `Log[k]->q`:

```
eq3 = Map[Divide[#, E^y[z]*r] &, eq2] /. 
   Log[E^-a_*b_] :> -a + Log[b] /. Log[k] -> q

(* Derivative[1][y][z] == q - y[z] *)
```

Done. Now one can solve this equation:

```
sl = DSolve[eq3, y, z]

(*  {{y -> Function[{z}, q + E^-z C[1]]}}  *)
```

and substitute the replacements back:

```
x[t] == Exp[sl[[1, 1, 2, 2]] /. {z -> r*t, q -> Log[k]}]

(*  x[t] == E^(E^(-r t) C[1]) k  *)
```

[image]

Done. One can, further, analyze the result, but this is another story.

Have fun!